# How to grant web access to individual Windows apps?

Tags: windows-10, firewall

**Condition:** the Windows Defender firewall is configured to block outgoing web connections by default.

**What's needed:** allow some Windows apps (News, Weather, etc.) to access the Web.

**Problem:** the owner of the folder "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" is TrustedInstaller and this folder is not viewable even with admin privileges. So one cannot find out the paths of app executables for specifying them in firewal rules.

**Question:** how to grant web access to individual Windows apps?

My guessing is that one needs to list the contents of "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" folder somehow. But how can it be done?

UPDATE: Many thanks to harrymc for pointing me in the right direction. When he said that the program Everything can access the folder contents I began to think along the following lines: how can a program installed by a user have more privileges than the user himself?  If the program can list the folder's contents then there surely must be a way for the user to do that without a third-party program. And then it's dawned on me to run the PowerShell as admin and use good old "ls".

Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the free [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) tool to search for the file.
It works as a system service and so can access the `WindowsApps` folder.

For example, searching for `*news*.exe` in the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\`,
the search term is:

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\" *news*.exe
```

Which finds:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingNews_4.28.3242.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.Msn.News.exe`.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: There are many alternative solutions. Everything is one of my most useful tools, so I took the opportunity to recommend it. If my answer has led to a solution, you might mark it as accepted.